# Can I build my meshes with a vector (OpenGL)

Tags: c++, opengl, mesh, vertex

I am trying to build my mesh by passing in the informations with a vector. I thought it would must be the same. But it is not working.
The actual information in this vector must be correct so I am actual pretty sure the problem is the building the actual bufferData.

Does somebody has a hint what is going wrong there? Or how I maybe do it in a better way?

```
void MeshBuilder::buildMesh(std::vector<Vertex> vert, std::vector<int> index){
Vertex vertex;
//Vertex Array Object: Binds Buffer Obj
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

std::vector<GLfloat> verticies;
for (int i = 0; i < vert.size(); i++) {
    verticies.push_back(vert[i].getPosition().x);
    verticies.push_back(vert[i].getPosition().y);
    verticies.push_back(vert[i].getPosition().z);
    verticies.push_back(vert[i].getNormals().x);
    verticies.push_back(vert[i].getNormals().y);
    verticies.push_back(vert[i].getNormals().z);
    verticies.push_back(vert[i].getTexture().x);
    verticies.push_back(vert[i].getTexture().y);
}

std::vector<int> indicies;
for (int i = 0 ; i < index.size(); i++) {
    indicies.push_back(i);
}

//Vertex Buffer Object
GLuint vbo;
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticies.size()*sizeof(GLfloat), &verticies, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
//Attributes
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, vertex.SIZE*4, (GLvoid*)0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, vertex.SIZE*4, (GLvoid*)12);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, vertex.SIZE*4, (GLvoid*)24);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

glBindVertexArray(0);

//Element Buffer Object
glGenBuffers(1, &ebo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicies.size()*sizeof(int), &indicies, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

std::cout << "Mesh buildet..." << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The `&verticies` will give you the addres of your `std::vector` container, not the address of the first element.

Comment: I try it also with "&indicies.front()" and "&indicies[0]" but it is not showing anything

Comment: You never bind the `vao` you create at the start of the method.

Comment: oh, I forgot this. it is binding it know and updatet it in the code above. But still not working.

Comment: `vertex.SIZE*4` doesn't seem right for your stride; it should be `sizeof(GLfloat)*8`, because that's what you put into the vector.

Comment: vertex.SIZE actually hold only the int 8. and 4 should be the sizeof(GLfloat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your method declaration & definition try changing it from `void MeshBuilder::buildMesh(std::vector<Vertex> vert, std::vector<int> index);` to `void MeshBuilder::buildMesh(std::vector<Vertex>& vert, std::vector<int>& index)` to pass by reference instead of making a copy; this will help speed things up.

The only other thing I can see that may cause a problem is that you are stopping your vertex array before you define your indices. Try moving your `glBindVertexArray(0);` that is before your `//Element Buffer Object` code to be called after these three lines of code. See if this makes a difference.

Also make sure that you do the following before the end of this function or after this function is called:

- Disable Attribute Pointers
- The Next Two Below Must Be After Vertex Array Buffer Is Unbound:

  - Stop Buffer Index - `glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );`
  - Stop Buffer - `glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );`